# Bound of the Wave Equation in 3 dimensions

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality, partial-differential-equations

For n=3, $u(x,t)\in C^2$ and $\Box u=0$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^3,\ t\geq0$.
Assume U(t)=$\sum_{|a|\leq2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |D^au(x,t)|dx<\infty$ for $t=0$.
a) Show that there exists a constant K independent of u such that:

> $|u(x,t)|\leq \frac{K}{t}U(0)$ for $t>0$

Hint: Write the integrand in Kirchoff's formula as:

> $\sum_i[\frac{1}{ct}(th(y)+g(y))(y_i-x_i)+ctg_{y_i}(y)]\xi_i $

where $\xi_i=\frac{y_i-x_i}{ct}$  are the directions cosines of the exterior surface normal. Convert the integral to one extended over the solid sphere $|y-x|<ct$.

b)Show that

> $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{U(t)}{t}=0$

Implies that u vanishes identically.
Hint: Apply (a) to the function $v(x,t,T)=u(x,T-t)$ for large T.

Exercise 4, page 133 of [Partial Differential Equations, John F.](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387906096#aboutBook)

My attempt was:
$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{4\pi c^2 t^2}\sum\int_{\partial B}\frac{1}{2ct}(th(y)+g(y))D_{y_i}\lvert y-x\rvert^2 \xi_i+ctD_{y_i}g(y)\xi_i dS(y)$.
Then using Green's identities to transform it into:
$u(x,t)= \frac{1}{4\pi c^2 t^2}\sum\int_{B}\frac{1}{2ct}(th(y)+
g(y))\Delta_{y_i}\lvert y-x\rvert^2+ \frac{1}{2ct}D_{y_i}(th(y)+g(y))D_{y_i}\lvert y-x\rvert^2+ct \Delta_{y_i}g(y)\ dy$

$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{4\pi c^2 t^2}\sum\int_{B}\frac{1}{ct}(th(y)+g(y))+ \frac{1}{ct}D_{y_i}(th(y)+g(y))( y_i-x_i)+ct\Delta_{y_i}g(y)\ dy$.

$u(x,t)\leq\frac{1}{4\pi c^2 t}\int_R |\Delta g| + \frac{1}{t}|Dg| + \frac{3}{c^2t^2}|g| + |Dh| +\frac{3}{ct}|h|dy$.
For $ct>1$ there is a constant K such as $|u(x,t)|\leq\frac{K}{t}U(0)$.

*Based on [page 17](https://users.math.msu.edu/users/yanb/847ch4.pdf)  $U(0)=\int_R|g|+|h|+|Dg|+|Dh|+|D^2g|dy$. But how is it computed?*

b)$v(x,t,T)=u(x,T-t)\implies v(x,T-t,T)=u(x,t)$
$|u(x,t)|=v(x,T-t,T)\leq\frac{K}{T-t}U(T)$, therefore for $T\rightarrow\infty\implies |u(x,t)=0|$

Comment: This is a nice exercise, but you should provide some of your ideas and show some effort if you want to be well received here. Please edit your question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I edited the question as much as I could.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, here's a +1 from me , for this question definitely shows research effort. And since you showed you attempt, I have voted to reopen this too.